# Which book had Darth Vader having a chance to get a new suit?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, star-wars-legends

Does anyone know which book, comic, etc. discussed that Vader had a chance to get a more modern breathing suit? But he might die while changing into the new suit from the old one. I remember reading it somewhere but can't remember where.

Comment: I don't recall any *EU* story with this mentioned. In fact, it's established fairly early that Vader can never leave the suit outside of his own private chamber.

Answer (score 3):

*[Death Star](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/786729.Death_Star?from_search=true&search_version=service)*

[image]

From the [Darth Vader Armor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader's_armor#Discomfort.2C_limitations_and_enhancements) Star Wars Wikia entry:

> As of 0 BBY, Vader was given an opportunity to have a new suit built for him. This suit would have been far more advanced, technologically superior, and much more comfortable than his original. However, to be placed into this new suit, Vader would have to have had his prosthetics disconnected and his life support systems temporarily disabled. Since the process was considered far too risky, and most likely would result in his death, the idea was abandoned.

They reference that to *Death Star*.

Comment: Considering he literally joined the Sith to learn how to sustain life via the Force, it's a real wonder he didn't kill Palpatine sooner.